# How to find object / widget by name in GTK3+, Glade

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am writing a simple form in GTK+3, using `C`.

The form has a text entry called `txtPrompt`, and a submit button `btnSend`, created in Glade.

I am trying to access the text in textview upon button press and to do so, am using the following callback handler:

```
GtkBuilder *builder;

void onSubmit(GtkWidget * widget, GdkEvent * event, gpointer data) {
    GObject * textView = gtk_builder_get_object(GTK_BUILDER(builder), "txtPrompt");
    gchar * input = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(textView));
    g_print(input);
    g_print("Submit clicked\n");
}
```

However it does not work and yields this:

```
(client:12905): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `<invalid>' in cast to `GtkBuilder'

(client:12905): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_get_object: assertion `GTK_IS_BUILDER (builder)' failed

(client:12905): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion `GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

(client:12905): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_print: assertion `format != NULL' failed
Submit clicked
```

Help?

Comment: Are you constructing builder using `gtk_builder_new()` ?

Comment: yes it is using `gtk_builder_new()` ...

Comment: to access builder, i left the pointer as a global -for now-.  It gives an error still.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to create `builder`? And are you sure that code runs before `onSubmit()`?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure.  The problem was `g_object_unref(G_OBJECT (builder));` .  It would be better to pass the builder as a param, but unsure how to with the automatic binding in Glade / GTK

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I uncommented this line from the `main()` code:

```
g_object_unref(G_OBJECT (builder));
```

According to a forum post, this REMOVES the reference to builder entirely!

One can then call stuff on builder within a signal handler, as per normal.